# Azure VMs and load balancing

Tags: azure, load, virtual-machine

am new to windows azure. I recently set up a vm and host a website, according to the SLA i need to have 2 VMs in the availability set. Now i did set up the second VM.

My questions what do i need to use the second VM for?

if i setup load balancing does azure redirect user to the second VM? this second VM has nothing in it.

Please i will like to know this and is it possible to replicate the content of the first VM to the second one, so each time the first one is down the second VM can take over.

Thanks

Comment: This should be posted on ServerFault, not StackOverflow, since it's not about programming.

Answer (score 1):

At first, You must understand the statement of minimum two machines to get 99.95% SLA. It is not about "reserving" resources for use in case of fault or update (fault domain and update domain in availability set). Your application must be created as multi-tenant, so You need to run Your application on two servers, connected to the availability set. You can synchronize storage with GlusterFS (if You use Linux) or other distributed file system. You also can use Azure Files service (SMB as a service) to share storage. For sharing DB (in example MySQL) You need a cluster (independent or distributed through Your two machines).
So... You must to start think in "cloud way" instead of typical one VM administration.

Comment: thanks i really appreciate this you have just thrown more light to the issue am facing. So i have seen GlusterFS i will try my hands on that for file synchronization. Please can you explain more on the db sharing, do i have create a new availability and vm's set for mysql separately? or can i replicate data between the to vm?. Please your response is highly appreciated. Any resource or article on how to go about this is welcomed, thanks